# Rails Validations neat errors in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling

So i made a Validation that will check gender if an accurate ID number is inputted, if the data is incorrect then an error will appear beneath the select within the form.

```
.col
  %h4 Participant
  = f.field(:full_name, :label => "Full name *")
  = f.field(:id_number)
  = f.field(:gender, :field_type => :select, :choices => GENDER_SELECT, :label => 'Gender *')
  %br #note i added this as the 'hacky' fix
  = f.field(:race, :field_type => :select, :choices => RACE_SELECT, :label => 'Race *')
```

without the `%br` i have the form return the error like this

[image]

Is there a less hacky way so that when the error is displayed that it renders it something like this. so that the errors don't overflow onto other form elements

```
%br
= participant.errors[:gender]
%br
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.field-error
    = participant.errors[:gender]
```

Then use css to style the field-error class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS styles to control the errors layout/visual appearance instead of additional HTML tags.